# Angular - Facebook like box is blank despite prerender.io and proper og:tags

Tags: javascript, angularjs, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a problem with facebook like button. 
I am using [prerender.io](http://prerender.io) to have some content easly crawlable by bots and **it works fine**.

When I use https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/ to debug urls, **it works fine**.

BUT: 
when I add this directive, I have 50% that I will get blank page (on fb like button).

```
.directive('fbLike', ['$rootScope', '$compile', '$location',
function ($rootScope, $compile, $location){
  return {
    transclude: true,
    template: '<div ng-transclude></div>',
    link: function (scope, element){
      var tmpl = '<div class="fb-like" data-href="' + $location.absUrl() + '" data-layout="box_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="false"></div>';

      function compile (){
        element.html($compile(tmpl)(scope));
        if (typeof FB !== 'undefined'){
          FB.XFBML.parse();
        }
      }

      if ($rootScope.loaded === true){
        compile();
      }

      $rootScope.$watch('loaded', function(newValue){
        if (newValue){
          compile();
        }
      });
    }
  };
}])
```

Screen below:
[image: This is what I get.]

Answer (score 0):

Facebook's crawler doesn't like to wait very long for the response so you need to make sure your pages will load as fast as possible in case someone shares a URL that isn't already cached on Prerender.io.

Feel free to send me the URLs that you're sharing and I'll be happy to work with you to make sure we can render your URLs as fast as possible.

Happy to help!

todd@prerender.io